# Kinesis producers for web apps

Tags: amazon-kinesis, data-ingestion

I was playing around with Kinesis data streams, and was wondering how a web app or mobile app would send events to kinesis data streams. One way of doing this would be to set up a java spring based endpoint that the web app or mobile apps would post to, and the server would aggregate/collect records using KPL. Another would be to post events to an intermediate store like sqs or a database and then send those over to kinesis data streams through lambda. But in both those cases, I feel like the intermediary step reduces the 'real time' essence of data streams. Anyone have any thoughts/experience for such a scenario?